# Sharepoint 2016 updates

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

1. when SharePoint 2016 release? and where can I find latest updates released for this product?
2. Sharepoint 2016 can be installed on windows server 2012 r2 and SQL server 2012 enterprise?

Comment: Google search is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The current version is the SharePoint 2016 Release Candidate. A release date for the RTM version has not been announced. See: [SharePoint Server 2016 and Project Server 2016 Release Candidate available.](https://blogs.office.com/2016/01/20/sharepoint-server-2016-and-project-server-2016-release-candidate-available/)
2. See: [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.16).aspx)

**UPDATE:**

Based on the comments below I have to revise the first answer:

1. SharePoint Server 2016 went RTM on March 14 however it will not be generally available until sometime in May (probably May 4). See: [SharePoint 2016 RTM and the Future of SharePoint event](https://blogs.office.com/2016/03/14/sharepoint-2016-rtm-and-the-future-of-sharepoint-event/)

Comment: Is sharepoint 2016 RTM version not released?

Comment: Yes, RTM was released March 14th: https://blogs.office.com/2016/03/14/sharepoint-2016-rtm-and-the-future-of-sharepoint-event/ and the trial can be downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51493, but you can't buy it until early May (probably May 4th)

Comment: Wow! How did I miss that???? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll find out more in May at Bill Baer's webinar on May 4th. See https://vts.inxpo.com/Launch/QReg.htm?ShowKey=30784&AffiliateData=MechanicsBlog for registration.

SharePoint Server 2016 does not support SQL Server 2012, but does support Windows Server 2012 R2. It does support SQL Server 2014, and on RTM, SQL Server 2016.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.16).aspx#section4

Answer (score 1):

On May 4, 2016(dates may Change) will be big day, when MSFT will unveil it for general public. You can [register that webinar](https://vts.inxpo.com/scripts/Server.nxp?LASCmd=AI:4;F:QS!10100&ShowKey=30784&AffiliateData=RTMBlog&Referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.office.com%2F2016%2F03%2F14%2Fsharepoint-2016-rtm-and-the-future-of-sharepoint-event%2F).

Also if you want to learn more about it before hand then [join this webinar on March 31, 2016](http://yourock.share-gate.com/sharepoint-2016-with-bill-baer/)

You cant use SQL Server 2012 as SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 (SP1) is minimum requirement. Read more about [this technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.16).aspx#section4)